# logger doesn't propogate to children module

Tags: python, logging

I have two files, `a.py` and `b.py`.

This is written in both of the files:

```
import logging
import sys
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
```

Now when I import a method from `b.py` to `a.py`, the logs from method of `b.py` do not show on console.

Calling from `a.py` is like `b.method_name()`.

How do I show logs from `b.py` in console as well?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should NOT be adding handlers to your logger in library code. The point of the logging package is to separate logger calls (in library code) from logging configuration (at the application's top level).

Answer (score 0):

Given `a.py`:

```
import logging
import sys
import b


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))


def bar():
    logger.error("bar error")
    logger.info("bar info")
    logger.warning("bar warnign")

bar()    
b.foo()
```

and `b.py`:

```
import logging
import sys
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))

def foo():
    logger.error("foo error")
    logger.info("foo info")
    logger.warning("foo warnign")
```

I get following output:

```
bar error
bar warnign
foo error
foo warnign
```

Not sure how your files looks like, but by default, You won't see messages bellow certain logging level (in this case, lowest You'll see is `warning`).

Comment: If I do `print(logger.handlers)`
Inside the function it shows empty list, outside the function it shows streamhandler for `b.py`
`[<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x7fe84b803ba8>]`

Comment: Do You import `foo` as `from b import foo` or `from b import *`, or You do `import b`?

Comment: Well my packaging is like
`package.dir.a` , `package.b` and I import b to a, as `from package import b` , and use the method as `b.foo()`